# How to return 2 specific rows from a dataframe?

Tags: r

```
firstVector <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
secondVector <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
thirdVector <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")


myDataFrame <- data.frame(firstVector, secondVector, thirdVector)
```

How do I extract row 3 and 4 from my data frame? I want to print it row 3 and 4 in order it to look like this:

```
    firstVector secondVector thirdVector
3     C            3            c
4     D            4            d
```

Comment: Use row index, `myDataFrame[c(3:4),]`

Answer (score 0):

You can subset your dataframe like this [rows,columns]:

```
myDataFrame[c(3,4),]
```

In your case you want a vector containing rows 3 and 4, therefore c(3,4), you can add more columns in the vector to subset more rows, for example c(1,2,3,12).
If you dont provide an argument it returns the whole dimension. In your example you subset rows, and return all the columns

it's the same for columns:

```
myDataFrame[c(3,4),c(1,2)]
```

you can subset rows 3 and 4 and columns 1 and 2.

Another way to do this is using :
c(1:4) means from 1 to 4

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! However, is there a way that i can subset my dataframe from the element in the first row, not the row name (which is eg. 1,2,3,4). Basically, I can just call two specific row by just passing in C and D.

Comment: Yes, but i think you mean first column. myDataFrame[firstVector %in% c("C","D"),]   i.e  YourDataFrame[RowCondition,ColumnCondition]